# IIS website opening outside of server, but not internally

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, windows-server-2012

I have multiple sites hosted within an IIS server. Let me give you an example like:

demo.trial.com and demo.web.com

Under both these websites, I have created multiple pages like

trial1 under demo.trial.com and page1 under demo.web.com

The intention is that I should be able to browse demo.trial.com/trial1 and demo.web.com/page1. And I am able to do both these from my laptop.

The problem is that I am able to browse demo.trial.com/trial1 within the server without any issues, but browsing demo.web.com/page1 within the server shows me page cant be displayed. The bindings as well as other settings are same in both the websites, but not sure why demo.web.com/page1 is not opening within the server, but opens outside the server.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that the server (and it's browser) are unaware that `demo.web.com` is hosted locally. My recommendation would be to add the following record to the `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1  demo.web.com
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But that shouldn't be the ideal way of doing it, if my understanding is correct. Ideally the website hosted should be accessible inside the server.